# Creating Signature and Nonce for OAuth (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I'm looking to access SmugMug's API from my application to grab users' albums and images (the users have been authenticated via ruby's OmniAuth).

According to [SmugMug's OAuth API](http://wiki.smugmug.net/display/API/show+1.2.2?method=smugmug.albums.get), OAuth requires six parameters.

I can get the token with OmniAuth, and the timestamp should be easy (Time.now.to_i right?).  There are two things that I don't know how to generate -- the oauth_nonce and the oauth_signature.

According to the oauth docs, I generate the nonce via the timestamp, but how exactly would I do that?  Does it need to be a certain length and limited to certain characters?

And of course the signature.  How would I generate a HMAC-SHA1 sig with ruby?  I know the oauth gem can do it, but I'd rather generate it myself to use with OmniAuth.  Looking at the code, I'm having trouble deciphering how the oauth gem generates the sig.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the signature:

```
def sign( key, base_string )
  digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new( 'sha1' )
  hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest( digest, key, base_string  )
  Base64.encode64( hmac ).chomp.gsub( /\n/, '' )
end#def
```

You don't have to generate the nonce from the timestamp, but it can make sense since the timestamp is obviously unique, so it makes a good starting input for any randomisation function.

I use this, (that I got from another question on here and modified)

```
def nonce
  rand(10 ** 30).to_s.rjust(30,'0')
end#def
```

but you can use anything that generates a unique string.

See [this gist by erikeldridge on github](https://gist.github.com/383159) and [Beginner’s Guide to OAuth](http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iv-signing-requests/) for more

#### Edit

I've since found there's a better way to generate random strings in the Ruby standard library, [SecureRandom](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html).

Comment: I wanted to say thanks again as that gist you linked to has been incredibly helpful.  However, I had trouble getting it working with 1.9.2, and couldn't quite figure out why -- have you solved this problem?

Comment: I wrote this on 1.9.2 so if it's not working then perhaps it's something else? Do you have any error messages to share? I had to write a lot of logging statements before getting it to work, anything with encryption will require that and tests or you'll find it hard to track down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was talking of the gist you linked to, but I figured out the problem -- CGI.parse was turning the values of the url parameters into an array (which it didn't do in 1.8.7), which was screwing up my API call.  All is working.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: `nonce = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes 12`

Answer (score 5):

A nonce can also be simply a large-ish, properly random number - for example, using Ruby's SecureRandom class (don't use 'rand'):

```
require 'securerandom'
```

...

```
nonce = SecureRandom.hex()
```

This generates a 16-byte random number in hex format.

Comment: One question. This solution could be perfect, but it has one main problem. How can I save all nonces? I simply cant. A solution must be based on timestamp, anyway. See this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865690/whats-the-point-of-a-timestamp-in-oauth-if-a-nonce-can-only-be-used-one-time

Comment: You need a nonce cache, yes. The nonce cache is bounded by time.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't just use the Oauth ruby gems to do that ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I want to use OmniAuth (and have it set up) and am not sure how I would integrate it with oauth.  OmniAuth gets me everything but these two things so I'd rather just write them myself.

Comment: omniauth do all you want to you. no need to check the oauth params