# Do we really need "oauth_nonce"?

Tags: oauth

Right, I know how oauth works, but I don't know why we need `oauth_nonce`.

The specification says timestamp / nonce has to be unique to solve replay attacks, but what about if `consumer_key` is unique enough?

If `consumer_key` is not unique, how does it find corresponding `oauth_nonce`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keys are unique but don't change often. A nonce on the other hand needs to be unique per request.

Consider the following scenario. Prerequisites are: An attacker can spy on your communication but does not know any secrets. If there is no nonce, he can do a replay attack: He can simply duplicate and resend any of your  previous requests, because he knows the requests you already send are valid.

A nonce prevents this, as the server checks all recently used nonces ([there is a time limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865690/whats-the-point-of-a-timestamp-in-oauth-if-a-nonce-can-only-be-used-one-time)) and does not accept any nonce twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now i know it. I can not use key rather than nonce to identify the consumer because the consumer may request again, if use nonce we can use a unique nonce to avoid replay attack, but if i record consumer_key instead of nonce, it can not even do a normal request because i already record it consumer_key as   already visited