# PHP microtime() in javascript or angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, time

In PHP microtime() return the string in "microsec sec".

```
php microtime()
```

eg: '0.48445100 1470284726'

In JavaScript there is no default function for `microtime()`.
So divided the return type, where sec is in unix timestamp using `date.getTime()` returned the sec value, eg:

```
var date  = new Date();
var timestamp = Math.round(date.getTime()/1000 | 0);
```

Then how to get the 'microsec' value in JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript provide a high resolution timer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875625/does-javascript-provide-a-high-resolution-timer)

Comment: Subtract a rounded date from a date?

Comment: What do you really want to use this for? JS gives you millisecond resolution timestamps. That's not microseconds resolution, so dividing it up in some way isn't going to get you that. What's the use case?

Comment: purpose need to create oauth_nonce to generate url. but in PHP there is default function uses the microtime(), getting confuse what method to implement to replace microtime in javascript.

Comment: So what you really need is just a *random number*?

Comment: @deceze nonce tokens aren't random numbers. The timestamp needs to be close enough to `now` for the request to succeed. This prevents replay attacks.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23090269/1979230

Comment: @BrianHannay A nonce must contain a random component; if it’s just the current timestamp, it’s utterly *predictable*.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In PHP `microtime` actually gives you the fraction of a second with microsecond resolution.

JavaScript uses milliseconds and not seconds for its timestamps, so you can only get the fraction part with millisecond resolution.

But to get this, you would just take the timestamp, divide it by 1000 and get the remainder, like this:

```
var microtime = (Date.now() % 1000) / 1000;
```

For a more complete implementation of the PHP functionality, you can do something like this (shortened from [PHP.js](http://locutus.io/php/datetime/microtime/)):

```
function microtime(getAsFloat) {
    var s,
        now = (Date.now ? Date.now() : new Date().getTime()) / 1000;

    // Getting microtime as a float is easy
    if(getAsFloat) {
        return now
    }

    // Dirty trick to only get the integer part
    s = now | 0

    return (Math.round((now - s) * 1000) / 1000) + ' ' + s
}
```

**EDIT :**
Using the newer *High Resolution Time API* it's possible to get microsecond resolutions in [most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=high-resolution-time)

```
function microtime(getAsFloat) {
    var s, now, multiplier;

    if(typeof performance !== 'undefined' && performance.now) {
        now = (performance.now() + performance.timing.navigationStart) / 1000;
        multiplier = 1e6; // 1,000,000 for microseconds
    }
    else {
        now = (Date.now ? Date.now() : new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
        multiplier = 1e3; // 1,000
    }

    // Getting microtime as a float is easy
    if(getAsFloat) {
        return now;
    }

    // Dirty trick to only get the integer part
    s = now | 0;

    return (Math.round((now - s) * multiplier ) / multiplier ) + ' ' + s;
}
```

Comment: If you're using this to get a seemingly random number, as asked in the comments to the question, would advice against using the method that produces microseconds, as it doesn't seem to do too good a job at that yet!